# how to start an exe via eclipse plugin.xml button

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We want to start a windows "exe" in eclipse "rcp"...

Windows "exe" lies in a folder which is at the relative path of "eclipse.exe".

Now we want to add a button next to an existing button at our eclipse "rcp"...

So when this button is clicked i want to call the windows "exe" which lies at a folder next to "eclipse.exe".

How can i get the relative path of "eclipse.exe" so that i can get into the folder of the "exe" that i want to run, name it windows "exe"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Platform.getInstallLocation()` to get the installation location (`org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform`)

```java
URL installURL = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL();
```